# Unlist a list with more than one values in a row

Tags: r

I try to make an unlist from this commands:

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("I am loving it", "I am hating it but I go, and I teach"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myDfm <- df$text %>%
      tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
      tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart")))

data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("loving", "hating teach")
```

Here is an example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = 1:length(myDfm),text = unlist(myDfm))
  id         text
1  1       loving
2  2 hating teach
```

The error:

> Error in data.frame(id = 1:length(myDfm), text = unlist(myDfm)) :
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3

Comment: `data.frame(id = seq_along(myDfm), text = sapply(myDfm, paste, collapse = " "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply`and `paste0`:

```
data.frame(id = 1:length(myDfm),text = sapply(myDfm,  paste0, collapse = " "))
      id         text
text1  1       loving
text2  2 hating teach
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stack`

```
stack(lapply(myDfm, paste, collapse=" "))[2:1]
#     ind       values
#1 text1       loving
#2 text2 hating teach
```